# Ram overflow and long loading times, SQL query big data

Tags: sql, matlab, bigdata

I have an existing database from which I need to extract a single record that contains a total of 10 GB of data. I have tried to load the data with

```
conn = sqlite(databaseFile, 'readonly')
GetResult = [
            'SELECT result1, result2 ...... FROM Result '...
            'WHERE ResultID IN ......'
            ];
Data = fetch(conn, GetResult)
```

With this query, the working memory increases (16GB) until it is full, and then the software crashes.
I also tried to limit the result with

```
'LIMIT 10000'
```

at the end of the query and browse the results by offset. This works, but it takes 3 hours (calculated from 20 individual results) to get all the results. (Database can not be changed)

Maybe someone of you has an idea to get the data faster or in one query.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns? Are any of them large BLOBs? Also, I'm a little confused: you say "a single record", which to me means "one row", but the rest of this question sounds like there are several thousand rows in the result set?

Comment: Maybe I explained it a bit wrong, as you rightly said there are 10 million rows for which I need 9 columns from one table and another 6 columns from other tables, and in addition I have several where clauses and a total of 5 inner joins. The only problem is that when I try to load the dataset, the memory (RAM) runs full until Matlab crashes.

Comment: To add to your question, the dataset is of varchar and nvarchar type. As mentioned in my question, the database is predefined by the system, so I can't change it (not very powerful database ).

Comment: Gotcha. Text data is about your worst case scenario for memory usage from SQL results; it takes way more space than numeric data. Are the text columns high cardinality (lots of distinct values) or low cardinality (many copies of a small number of distinct values)?